# como mostrar todos los decimales de una division como 1/41 o 2/149 ya que uso BigDecimal y me arroja error

Tags: java-ee

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException:
>   Non-terminating decimal expansion; no exact representable decimal
>   result.

Me muestra este error al realizar una division `1/41` y da como resultado `50` decimales ya que los quiero mostrar todos pero no me los muestra que otra forma puedo mostrarlos se supone que el `BigDecimal` es para mostrar las cifras exactas si alguien me puede ayudar gracias

Answer (score 1):

Usando la clase [BigDecimal()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) es posible realizar dicha operación , aplicando  el método [divide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#divide-java.math.BigDecimal-) la cuál se le enviará tres parámetros : `numero2 , cantidad de cifras decimales` y  [Tipo de redondedo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html)

La clase [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) por defecto siempre trata de devolver el resultado exacto , al realizar la división con decimales infinitos lanzará dicha Exception.
Para solucionar esto es necesario especificar la `precisión(cantidad de cifras decimales)`. y además el [Tipo de redondedo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html) para la división a la división. [HALF_UP](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html#HALF_UP) en este caso.

```
BigDecimal num1 = new BigDecimal(1);
BigDecimal num2 = new BigDecimal(41);
BigDecimal result = num1.divide(num2,50,RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
System.out.println(result.toString());
```

[Para más detalles, Aquí](https://jaydeepm.wordpress.com/2009/06/04/bigdecimal-and-non-terminating-decimal-expansion-error/)

Comment: si amigo gracias ya lo habia intentado asi pero hay una division 1/14911941 que tiene como resultado 33.556 digitos decimales no se si limitando la cantidad de cifras sea la unica manera de hacerlo porque puede haber otra division que arroje como resultado mas digitos abria otra forma de hacer sin limitar la cantidad de cifras decimales

Comment: Creo que sería correcto limitar la precisión a una cifra determinada. De lo contrario puede que se vuelva a presentar la misma excepción.